# Change LDAP password encryption using django-python3-ldap

Tags: python, django, ldap, passwords

***EDIT 2:***

It seems that the migrate command is importing the data BUT the password is set to "unusable" as it is calling this method in the library:

```
# If the user was created, set them an unusable password.
if created:
   user.set_unusable_password() # Will call: self.password = make_password(None)
   user.save()
```

If anyone has a solution ? Did you manage to use django-python3-ldap with a different version?

---

***EDIT1:***

Does someone manage to use django-python3-ldap successfully and can show me his settings.
It is possible that I forgot a config in my settings...

Thank you!

---

I am using django-python3-ldap v0.11.2 for LDAP authentication in Django.

I successfully managed to connect to my ldap test server which I created with some dummy users.
The migration using this command: `python manage.py ldap_sync_users` works fine and is refreshing my db.

However, when I try to connect with one of the user, I am getting this error message:
`LDAP connect failed: LDAPInvalidCredentialsResult - 49 - invalidCredentials - None - INVALID_CREDENTIALS: Bind failed: Invalid authentication - bindResponse - None`.

I suspect this is because the stored password is incorrectly encrypted... This is because the following test works fine:

- Connect with a pre existing admin account
- Change the password for newly imported user **jdoe** to **abc**
- Log out
- The connection using user: **jdoe** and password **abc** now works perfectly fine!

Have anyone faced this issue before ? Or knows how to change the password encryption used by the migrate command ? Or maybe I missed an important LDAP configuration...

**Python LDAP settings:**

```
# LDAP Connection Settings
LDAP_AUTH_URL = "ldap://localhost:10389"
LDAP_AUTH_USE_TLS = None
LDAP_AUTH_SEARCH_BASE = "DC=example,DC=com"

LDAP_AUTH_USER_FIELDS = {
    "username": "uid",
    "first_name": "givenName",
    "last_name": "sn",
    "email": "mail",
    "password": "userPassword"
}

LDAP_AUTH_OBJECT_CLASS = "organizationalPerson"

LDAP_AUTH_USER_LOOKUP_FIELDS = ("username",)

LDAP_AUTH_CLEAN_USER_DATA = "django_python3_ldap.utils.clean_user_data"

LDAP_AUTH_SYNC_USER_RELATIONS = "django_python3_ldap.utils.sync_user_relations"

LDAP_AUTH_FORMAT_SEARCH_FILTERS = "django_python3_ldap.utils.format_search_filters"

LDAP_AUTH_FORMAT_USERNAME = "django_python3_ldap.utils.format_username_active_directory"
LDAP_AUTH_CONNECTION_USERNAME = 'uid=admin,ou=system'
LDAP_AUTH_CONNECTION_PASSWORD = 'secret'
```

**LDAP test user config:**

```
dn: cn=Jane Doe,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
cn: Jane Doe
sn: Doe
ou: site_admin
description: 19650324000000Z
employeeNumber: 12
givenName: Jane
mail: jane@example.com
telephoneNumber: 169-637-3314
telephoneNumber: 907-547-9114
uid: jdoe
userPassword:: abc
```

**Extract of my test db:**

Username | Password

jdoe...........| !ipxhdylGKTwILF...

OkUser......| **pbkdf2_sha256**$150000$PHBKev...

Thank you for your help

Comment: You tagged [tag:active-directory], but this doesn't look like Active Directory. What is your underlying LDAP server?

Comment: Indeed, I was too fast when tagging... This is a test LDAP server I created using "Apache Directory Studio". Do you want me to copy paste you my LDIF file I used to instantiate the users ?

Comment: I found this when digging in the ldap package:
# If the user was created, set them an unusable password.
if created:
   user.set_unusable_password()   # This line is setting a value that will never be a valid hash
I guess that's why the hash is just incorrect. This is not the behaviour described in the documentation. I am quite surprised...

Comment: I don't have any experience with Apache Directory Studio. I know Active Directory quite well, which is why I was confused :)

Comment: Np thank you for trying. I edited my question. I think something is wrong in my settings. That's the only reason... Unfortunately, there is nothing helpful when googling it

Comment: It isn't encryption, it is secure hashing.

Answer (score 0):

I finally decided to implement my own authenticate & get user method
which is:

- Checking if the user already exists (basic django authentication)
- If not, check if the user with the provided username is part of specific ad group. If he is part of it, create a user using the basic django:

```
User.objects.create_superuser(username=username,
                              email=mail,
                              password='mypassword',
                              first_name=first_name,
                              last_name=last_name)
```